# What browser is the "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)" user agent?

Tags: browsers, user-agent, java

Some of my users are logging in with this browser: `Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)`. What browser is this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025296/what-is-apache-httpclient-unavailable-error-android-google-app-engine

Comment: And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904467/android-http-user-agent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user agent belongs to [Apache HTTPComponents](http://hc.apache.org/), which is a Java library that handles HTTP request. For example: It ***could*** be an Android app that is using the library to send POST requests to your login script. The `UNAVAILABLE` part is typically where the version number is located. As far as I know, this user agent is used as the default user agent for requests (i.e. the developer failed to set a custom user agent while setting up their client)

Answer (score -1):

It's from Tor browsers like Orweb and Orfox.